# website not showing in google - need help with magento admin key search words

Tags: search, websites, meta

It has taken 7 months for my website to finally work properly. 
I have had problem after problem from developers and now that it's up and running I still do not know how to use Magento properly. I need help with my meta keywords. If someone can please help me. My website is www.glamoroushairstyles.com.au
I have tried to put in as many key search words as possible. I go into google and put in "ladies wigs" Australia. My website doesn't even show up.
When I put glamorous hairstyles in google it shows up on the first page. 
The problem is When a customer puts in the search word "wigs" (which is the product I am selling) my website is not showing at all.

Can someone please tell me where in admin do I change these details from google. 
I need to change this.

see link below:

https://www.google.com.au/#q=glamorous+hairstyles+australia

Glamorous Hairstyles - Finest Collection of Wigs and Hair ...
[glamoroushairstyles.com.au/](http://glamoroushairstyles.com.au/)

At Glamorous Hairstyles you will be satisfied with our Service, Quality and ... Glamorous Hairstyles invites you to our Elegant and Stylish Collection of Fine Wigs.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for posting. Unfortunately, while this question *involves* Magento, it is really about SEO practices and ranking. I took a look at your site and you currently have hundreds of keywords in your meta tags. To be honest, meta keywords are really no longer used, and this is a poor optimization practice. As the field of SEO is much too broad for this particular forum (Magento Q&A) I'm going to have to close this question as off-topic. I would highly suggest that you visit again soon if you have more specific Magento questions. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and page rank, not about Magento.

Comment: From Colorado, I search for "glamorous wigs australia" and you're showing up on the first page. Keep running your site and making customers happy and you will improve.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I change my information in Magento admin? I did this in January and I can't remember.     I want to change this description :  At Glamorous Hairstyles you will be satisfied .................                                Glamorous Hairstyles - Finest Collection of Wigs and Hair ... glamoroushairstyles.com.au/

At Glamorous Hairstyles you will be satisfied with our Service, Quality and ... Glamorous Hairstyles invites you to our Elegant and Stylish Collection of Fine Wigs.

Comment: You can do this in System > Config > Design > HTML Head. But, this is a separate question; closing the original as OT. :-)

Comment: First thing, despite Magento including it, don't waste any time on the Meta Keyword tag content. It got spammed early on, no search engines actually use it. Second thing, wigs is so generic that you need to work on **specific unique content about the type of wigs** you provide, not the **wigs** keyword itself if you don't want to get buried. That's what the **page title**, **product name** and **product description** are for. The more you say, the better you rank.

Comment: thank you for the information . I thought the Meta Description/keywords were more important. I will add more content

Comment: This is a business topic - you can read this http://www.warriorforum.com/showthread.php?p=9395555#post9395555 and look around here http://www.warriorforum.com/search-engine-optimization/. Problems - you are running on GoDaddy with ~10s page loads (should be 1-2s) - the layout is all over the place such as colour & size being non-aligned - you have index.php so your config is not setup correctly - the site does not provide 'trust'.

Comment: Hi It's good to get some feedback seeing as I am new to all of this. Can you explain to me 10s page loads (should be 1-2s) index.php ?? Config not set up correctly?? Size non aligned. None of this was ever explained to me. There must be something in admin to align the size? Just thought I would ask.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Unlike the `Meta Keywords` tag which is totally ignored, `Meta Description` is used but only important in that it may be used for the content snippet that gets returned on the Search Engine Results Page (SERP), BUT it is not used by any search engine for determining search results. Nicer snippet, no contribution to search relevancy. Spend time on having a short relevant informational blurb, but don't waste time being overly elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're maybe new to internet retailing — there's an entire professional services segment out there that's dedicated to setting your site up correctly so it appears in the best possible light to search engines (like Google).  SEO, or Search Engine Optimization.  There's some companies that take a "let's do what Google wants us to" approach — these are called "white hat" firms.  There's other firms that take a "let's trick Google into listing this site higher — these are black hat firms.  Most people doing SEO fall into a grey area, and Google's pretty cagey about the rules.

If you want to dip your toe in this pool try the Google Webmaster Tools — this is a free service offered by Google that can help you find obvious errors with your site.  That said, there's no great simple answer here — every wig store wants to be listed first on Google's front page, and part of running an online store is competing on SEO ranking with other people in your vertical.

Good luck!